# firebase.database() is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, typeerror

Error message:

```
TypeError: _this.db is not a function
```

Code:

```
import app from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

const config = {
  apiKey: "some-api-key",
  authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "aofndiuf",
  storageBucket: "project-somenumber.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "793813245724y6597"
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
  }
  //  Auth API

  doCreateNewsletter = (news, name, description, email) => {
    const newsletter = { news, name, description, email };
    const newPostKey = this.db()
      .ref()
      .child("newsletters")
      .push().key;
    return this.db
      .ref()
      .child("/newsletters/" + newPostKey)
      .set(newsletter);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned `this.db` like this:

```
this.db = app.database();
```

But then you refer to it later like this:

```
const newPostKey = this.db()
    ...
```

The object returned from `app.database()` isn't a function, so you can't call it like a function as you are now.  It's a [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database) object.  Perhaps you can just get rid of those parenthesis to make your code work the way you intended.

Comment: He did `const newPostKey = this.db()
      .ref()
      .child("newsletters")
      .push().key;` there's a chaining. I guess that's not the issue.

Comment: It's not the issue.  The parenthesis after this.db that makes it a function call is the issue, as I explained.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense 